# We are trying to migrate a VB5 program (50k Lines) to VB6 encountering multiple errors

Tags: vb6, migration, virtual-machine, vb5

We are trying to migrate a VB5 program (50k Lines) to VB6.

When we loaded the program into VB5 we would get Threed not found, So we did a RegSvr32 on all of our OCX and now we load correctly.

When we do a Make we encounter pnlcolor not found, pnlstatus not found, etc. Many of the errors were about members of an activex (Threed) missing members.

Note: This code is operational in a VM we created years ago. And runs with no errors in the (XP)VM to this day, but we can't load new DLLs into the (XP)VM or run the debugger which is really hindering development. I am tired of using MSGBOX to debug code.
We are trying to bring the code out of the (XP)VM and run it in Windows 10 or Windows 7.

This is where we encounter the problems. Any help or suggestions other than a complete rewrite would be appreciated. We have to ship product and will start rewriting in the near future.

**Update**: When I got 'Sheridan 3d Controls" to show up in Components and check the control it displays,  "Name conflicts with existing module, project, or object library"

Comment: If you can edit your question to add more specific details like error messages that would help to understand the problem more.  I'm sure you will be able to get this working, VB6/VB6 have poor tools for managing dependencies, its probably just a matter of figuring out what you are missing.

Comment: Try installing the Sheridan/Infragistics library instead of manually registering the individual components.

Comment: Open your exe file at (XP)VM machine with notepad and find all occurrences of .dll and .ocx files and check if those files exist at your development machine.

Comment: So, assuming you have the OCX in the proper directory and registered (including considering x64 architecture), in the VB6 IDE, does the 'Sheridan 3d Controls' show up, and is it checked, in the Project Components panel?  Ctrl-T or Menu Project -> Components...  ?

Comment: While a vb5 to vb6 migration should be an extremely minor upgrade, assuming you have your dependencies worked out and can install them, I would suggest giving .Net a try.  Get 2008 and run the upgrade wizard, it will almost certainly have more errors than you have currently, but will land you in an infinitely better place for going forward. And 50k is a fairly small project, should be doable by just manually fixing the errors.